# Probability in Poker of a rainbow flop

Tags: probability

Poker with three community cards (flop). I need to calculate probability of all three cards of 52-card standard deck to be all of different suits.

**My first method is:**

1st card: doesnt matter, 
2nd card: needs to be 39 out of 51;
3rd card: needs to be 26 out of remaining 50.

Thus, p_rainbow flop = 39/51*26/50 = 0.3976

**The second method:**

Calculate at least two of the same suit cards to be on the flop:

C(13,2) = 78

Multiply by 4 kind of suits = 312,
And multiply by 50 (Any of the remaining cards) = 15,600

Divide by total no of flops C(52,3) = 22,100

P_at least two of same suit cards = 0.7059

Why do I have such difference? Which method is wrong (I suspect the second one), but cannot find the flaw in reasoning, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've anticipated, the second method is applied in error.  One accurate way to count is as follows:

You have *exactly* two cards in the same suit in $C(13, 2)C(31, 1) = 3042$ ways.  You have *exactly* three cards in the same suit in $C(13, 3) = 286$ ways.  Thus, for all four suits, you have *at least* two cards in that suit in $4(3042+286) = 13312$ ways.  (This is safe because there is no way to have two suits with two cards each in a three-card flop.)  Divide that by the $C(52, 3) = 22100$ ways to flop three cards, and you get $0.60236$ approximately, which is $1-0.39764$ approximately (the result from your first method).

---

The error in your application of the second method is that you overcount three-card flushes; you count them three times per suit, rather than just once.  That results in an excess of $4(3-1)(286) = 2288$, the exact difference between $13312$ and $15600$.

Answer (score 0):

The second method doesn't work because you treat the cards as independent instead of dependent. You do $\binom{13}{2}$=78, but that doesn't account for the fact that the first and second card have a different probability of being drawn.

Comment: That's not really the problem; OP is first counting the number of *ways* to select the three-card flops that have the desired property; the changing probabilities are accounted for when they divide by $C(52, 3)$ at the end, as the $52$, $51$, and $50$ end up in the denominator.